# GooglePlatformTextToSpeech. Помогите сменить голос . Муж на Жен

Tags: android

Пишу программу на AIMYBOX
не могу сменить голос МУЖ на ЖЕН, пожалуйста помогите.

```
private fun createAimybox(context: Context): Aimybox {

    val unitId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    val textToSpeech = GooglePlatformTextToSpeech(context, Locale("Ru"))
    val speechToText = GooglePlatformSpeechToText(context, Locale("Ru"))

    val dialogApi = AimyboxDialogApi(AIMYBOX_API_KEY, unitId)

    return Aimybox(Config.create(speechToText, textToSpeech, dialogApi))
}
```

Comment: если вы даже программно попытаетесь сменить не факт что пользователь это услышит, так как нужно еще скачать голосовые данные отдельно

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение сменить метод
`GooglePlatformSpeechToText`
На
`GoogleCloudSpeechToText`